# Removing html tags and entities from string in python

Tags: python, html

I am getting xml data from api.careerbuilder.com
Particularly, the string contains some html entities I am willing to remove, to no effect!

I have tried doing this:

```
import re
re.sub('\&amp;lt;.*?\&amp;gt;', '', job_title_text)
```

and this

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()

strip_tags(job_title_text)
```

and finally this

```
import lxml.html
(lxml.html.fromstring(job_title_text)).text_content()
```

But all of these were failures. The second approach deleted html entities like "&amp" but the text inside the tags was left, that is "pbrspan", for example. Third one completely ruined everything, no data was shown at all, instead

> < bound method HtmlElement.text_content of < Element html at 0x33717d8> >

Finally, I suspect, that the regex I have written is entirely wrong.
Any ideas, how this can be handled?

Comment: `text_content` is a method, not an attribute -- meaning you need to call it (`text_content()`) for it to yield anything useful.

Comment: @MaxNoel ah, sorry, you are right, that is a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression

(\&lt\;).*?(\&gt\;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use BeautifulSoup to remove tags, pretty well documented, http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Removing%20elements